# Regular Expression match term within ul class

Tags: regex

I have the following list of links and I would like some help devising a regex expression (in my case i'm using regexr.com - have started with this `<ul class=".*item-list.*`. This matches everything up until "example-nav">) to match everything within a ul class containing the phrase "item-list" - all the way up until the terminating `</ul>`. Only looking to match everything between the ul tags. Is this possible?

```
<ul class="some__links item-list id="example-nav">
<li>
<a href="http://uat.abc/info/contact_us1">Contact us</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://uat.abc/info/Home">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://uat.abc/info/Social_media">Social Media</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Language? Environment? Your attempts?

Comment: You'd better not use regexps to parse HTML. Use a specialized parser.

Comment: I've edited my question to add this information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have managed to work on a solution that suits my needs:

`.*item-list[\s\S]*?<\/ul>`

This grabs everything between item-list and the `</ul>`. May of use to something